# why does perf script not work?

Tags: linux, perf

As a green figure in Linux, I want to use 'perf' in order to generate a Flame Graph.
To ensure proper operation, I followed the instructions of 'Flame Graph' official github page[https://github.com/brendangregg/FlameGraph]

However, when I used the command `pref script > out.pref`, these errors occurred:

`no symbols found in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/vmwgfx_dri.so, maybe install a debug package?
Failed to open /tmp/perf-6637.map, continuing without symbols
Failed to open /tmp/perf-6663.map, continuing without symbols
Failed to open /tmp/perf-6674.map, continuing without symbols
Failed to open /tmp/perf-6703.map, continuing without symbols
Failed to open /tmp/perf-6713.map, continuing without symbols
Failed to open /tmp/perf-6720.map, continuing without symbols
Failed to open /tmp/perf-6755.map, continuing without symbols
Failed to open /tmp/perf-6772.map, continuing without symbols`

I searched Google and perf's WiKi for many times and found another command `perf script -i perf.data % > out.pref`, which actually works.

But the next command `perl ../FlameGraph/stackcollapse-perf.pl  perf.unfold & > perf.folded` would issue this error:

`[1]+  Stopped                 perf script -i perf.data`

It seems like it also cannot solve this problem. I tried rebuilding perf for my system from source but that didn't seem to help either.

I've tried multiple variations of this, but none of them seem to work. What would be the best way to do that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to resolve symbol issues, you can try doing:

```
# Install the debugging symbols for vmwgfx_dri and your kernel using something 

dnf debuginfo-install -y mesa-dri-drivers
dnf debuginfo-install -y kernel
```

I think with the flamgraph tool, you simple need to be in the same directory as your perf.data file and then you run:
flamegraph > my_flamegraph.svg

Then you open my_flamegraph.svg in a browser or with an svg viewer of some sort.

perf script will show you the textual version of the stacks of your programs that you profiles with perf, which can be very useful as well.